# How to configure slurm on ubuntu 20.04 with minimum requirements?

Tags: configuration, slurm, ubuntu-20.04, sbatch

I am trying to set-up configuration file on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried several thing and searched for errors on other websites ([link1](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm_ug_2011/Basic_Configuration_Usage.pdf), [link2](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3205), [link3](https://serverfault.com/questions/960537/unable-to-contact-slurm-controller)) and [slurm-website](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) as well. Another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002755/emulating-slurm-on-ubuntu-16-04) on SO as well.

Given the following information about my computer, **what is the minimum required information must be provided in slurm.conf file**.

The general information for my computer;

```
RAM: 125.5 GB 
CPU: 1-20 (Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v3 @ 3.10GHz × 20 )
Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] / NVIDIA Corporation 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit
```

and I want to have 2 nodes with 10 CPUs for each and 1 node for GPU.

**I have tried the followings;**

After configuration and running the followings;

```
>sudo systemctl restart slurmctld
```

with no error. But I got error witj slurmd.

```
> sudo systemctl restart slurmd
```

Error is as below;

```
Job for slurmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status slurmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

if I run "`systemctl status slurmd.service`"

```
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-06-06 21:47:26 CEST; 1min 14s ago
       Docs: man:slurmd(8)
    Process: 52710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Here is my configuration file slurm.conf generated by configurator_easy.html and saved in `/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf`

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
SlurmctldHost=myhostname
#
AuthType=auth/menge
Epilog=/usr/local/slurm/epilog
Prolog=/usr/local/slurm/prolog
FirstJobId=0
InactiveLimit=120
JobCompType=jobcomp/filetxt
JobCompLoc=/var/log/slurm/jobcomp
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
MaxJobCount=10000
#PluginDir=/usr/local/lib
ReturnToService=0
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd.spool
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm-llnl/slurm.state
SwitchType=switch/none
TmpFS=/tmp
WaitTime=30

SlurmctldPidFile=/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmdUser=root
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
#
# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
ClusterName=cluster
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
#JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
#SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/SlurmctldLogFile
#SlurmdDebug=info
#SlurmdLogFile=
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=Linux[1-32] State=UP
NodeName=DEFAULT State=UNKNOWN

PartitionName=Linux[1-32]  Default=YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on wsl and I was also struggling with setting up slurm as well. It looks like everything is running fine now. I am still a beginner..

I recommend you to really check the logs:

```
cat /var/log/slurmctld.log
cat /var/log/slurmd.log
```

In my case I had some permission issues and therefore had to make sure slurm related directories had to be owned by SlurmUser as defined in your config.

At first glance I see in your config the following lines which could cause the problem (if I compare the settings with mine):

- I wonder that you defined NodeName twice.
- In my case it has at first the value of SlurmctldHost

Hope something of the above mentioned can help.

Regards

Edit: I also would refer to the following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64439176/8362710), which could be similar to yours, if you run your command with sudo.